# In what ways was "Star Wars" influenced by "The Hidden Fortress"?

Tags: star-wars, reference, akira-kurosawa, george-lucas

I've heard many times that George Lucas got some of his ideas for his 1977 movie *Star Wars* from Akira Kurosawa's movie *The Hidden Fortress*. I can see how Tahei and Matashichi could have (in some ways) served as an inspiration for C3-P0 and R2-D2. Also, I noticed that the editing in *Star Wars*, with its frequent use of wipes, is similar to the editing in a lot of Kurosawa's movies from the 1950's, including not just *The Hidden Fortress*, but also *Seven Samurai* and others. But I was at a loss to come up with other ways in which *Star Wars* was influenced by *The Hidden Fortress*.

Are there other ways in which George Lucas's *Star Wars* was influenced by *The Hidden Fortress*, or more generally by Akira Kurosawa? What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mention the allusions between Tahei & Matashichi and R2-D2 & C-3PO seem to be the most obvious, but the way the film is cut/executed is also similar.

> *“**The one thing I was really intrigued by was the fact that the story
>   was told from the two lowest characters. I decided that would be a
>   nice way to tell the Star Wars story…That was the strongest influence.**
>   The fact that there was a princess trying to get through enemy lines
>   was more of a coincidence than anything else. In my film, the princess
>   is more of a stand-and-fight kind of princess. In the beginning, in
>   one of the first drafts, I did have a little bit more of her and a
>   Jedi, an older Jedi, trying to escape, but then it evolved into the
>   story of Luke.” - George Lucas*

However, as the following [Slashfilm](https://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-and-the-hidden-fortress/) article nicely explains, it seems the influence was stronger in previous drafts and with each update there were less and less influences in *A New Hope*.

> It’s true that earlier versions of the Star Wars script featured a
>   Jedi Knight that was much more active and older in the story, more
>   like Toshiro Mifune’s General Makabe in The Hidden Fortress. In fact,
>   **if you trace the lineage of drafts of the original Star Wars
>   screenplay and treatments, you can see that each revision took less
>   and less from Hidden Fortress**, with the earliest versions bearing the
>   most resemblance to the film.

However that influence re-emerged as Lucas began to continue on in The Skywalker Saga, especially the prequels...

> **Perhaps the Star Wars film that embodies The Hidden Fortress the most,
>   though, is The Phantom Menace. When you compare the premise of the two
>   movies, the resemblance is much more striking than with A New Hope. A
>   wisened general (Mifune and Liam Neeson) works to escape enemy
>   territory in order to get a young princess (Misa Uehara and Natalie
>   Portman) to safety so that she might save her people.** Along the way,
>   there are characters and situations that become reminiscent of The
>   Hidden Fortress, **but the most direct influence would be in the use and
>   sacrifice of handmaidens.**
>
> This use of handmaidens as doubles that is prevalent on the surface of
>   The Hidden Fortress is echoed in **The Phantom Menace with the use of
>   Sabe’s character (Keira Knightly) and the sacrifice of Princess Yuki’s
>   handmaiden is repeated in Attack of the Clones with Corde.**
>
> Although Padme is a “stand-and-fight” queen as much as her daughter
>   was as a princess, the story flourishes match between the prequels and
>   The Hidden Fortress are undeniable.

There are lots of videos made to show the parallels and influences: I will leave you with a few that Slashfilm also used as a point of reference, including one with George Lucas mentioning his Kurosawa influence, especially his **visual influence**.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give me a great answer to my question. I found the quotations from Lucas, as well as the Youtube video "Film Class #8", to be particularly helpful.

Comment: No problem, although I think Slashfilm deserves some credit for compiling one in one place for me! :)  Star Wars influences are pretty interesting in general. Even the Mandalorian has some nice homage to Seven Samurai most noticeably in 1.04: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Samurai

Comment: Also, I'm impressed that you were able to produce a quality answer so quickly. Thanks again!